# Asking for countdown while it's running

Tags: loops, countdown

I made a function with a while loop that countdown from a specific time and returns when Time is up.
But I want to make a function `get_time()` that tells me how much time is left on the timer while the other is running.
This second function is also a while loop that waits for my input to return where the countdown is at now.
So how can I make this get_time() function?

Comment: You can simply subtract current time with total time and also you can make you loop return time in every iteration

Comment: But I want it to do so when I tell it not every second or every lap of time.

Comment: Just to put you on context, it's part of an interactive app, I want it while the loop is running, all the other parts should be working and not wait for the loop to end.

Comment: Try use method in parallel: using multiprocessing with python

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following code (python) as reference

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def func1():
  print 'func1: starting'
  for i in xrange(10000000): pass
  print 'func1: finishing'

def get_time():
  print 'get_time: starting'
  for i in xrange(10000000): pass
  print 'get_time: finishing'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  p1 = Process(target=func1)
  p1.start()
  p2 = Process(target=get_time)
  p2.start()
  p1.join()
  p2.join()
```